# Does the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \cos(nt^2) dt$ converge or diverge?

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, definite-integrals, divergent-series

I know we can not write the primitive function of $\cos(nt^2)$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, thus I could not calculate the term $ \int_0^1 \cos(nt^2) dt$, could someone help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi :) we know $|t\cos(nt^2)|\leq|\cos(nt^2)|$ for $0\leq t\leq 1$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sustituting $u=\sqrt{n}t$, one has
$$\int_0^1 \cos(nt^2)dt = \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\int_0^{\sqrt{n}} \cos(u^2) dt $$

Since $\displaystyle\int_0^{+\infty} \cos(u^2) du$ is [well-known to be equal to](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral#Limits_as_x_approaches_infinity) $\dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2}}$, one gets

$$\int_0^1 \cos(nt^2)dt \mathop{\sim}\limits_{+\infty} \dfrac{1}{2}\sqrt{\dfrac{\pi}{2n}}$$

so by comparison, the series diverges.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^1 \cos(nt^2)\mathrm{d}t=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2n}{\pi}}\right)\sim\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}+\frac{\sin(n)}{2n}-\frac{\cos(n)}{4n^2}+O(n^{-2})$$
Where $C(z)$ is the Fresnel $C$ function.
$\sin(n)$ and $\cos(n)$ can be considered as constant $(s, c)$ since $-1\leq\sin(n),\cos(n)\leq 1$
In the series we have:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\int_0^1\cos(nt^2)\mathrm{d}t=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\int_0^1\cos(nt^2)\mathrm{d}t\sim1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2n}}+\frac{s}{2n}-\frac{c}{4n^2}\right]=\\
1+\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2\sqrt{2}}\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}}_{\to \infty}+\frac{s}{2}\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}}_{\to\infty}-\frac{c}{4}\underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}}_{\to\frac{\pi^2}{6}}\to\infty
$$
I removed $n=0$ from the series because we have $n$ in the denominator.

Comment: This answer is far from being totally rigorous : first, your symbol $\sim$ does not mean anything here (either you means an equivalent, but then only the first term of your developpement matters ; either you mean a full developpement but then you should use the symbol $=$) ; then you say "$\sin(n)$ and $\cos(n)$ can be considered as constants", which does not mean anything rigorous (they **are not** constants) ; finally, you are summing the $\sim$ relation, which is not allowed without assumption. I cannot underdand why this answer has two upvotes.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe In Italy we use $\sim$ to indicate that (and I think the context makes it clear). I don't pretend to write 30 lines to demonstrate such a simple thing, by "can be considered as constants" I mean that they are bounded above and below and that their limit at infinity is any number between -1 and 1 (but I think one who studies these things understands that even without such a long explanation) like if you were to calculate $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$

Answer (score 0):

$$S_p=1+\sum_{n=1}^{p} \int_0^1 \cos(nt^2)\, dt=1+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\,\sum_{n=1}^{p} \frac 1 {\sqrt n} C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2n}{\pi }} \right)$$
$$S=1+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \cos(nt^2)\, dt=1+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\,\sum_{n=1}^{p} \frac 1 {\sqrt n} C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2n}{\pi }} \right)+$$
$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\,\sum_{n=p+1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt n} C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2n}{\pi }} \right)$$

When $p$ is large (have a look at equation $(11)$ [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/FresnelIntegrals.html))
$$C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2n}{\pi }} \right)\simeq \frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sin (n)}{\sqrt{2 \pi n} }$$

$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\,\sum_{n=p+1}^{\infty} \frac 1 {\sqrt n} C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2n}{\pi }} \right)\simeq \frac 12 \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\color{red}{\sum_{n=p+1}^{\infty}{\frac 1 {\sqrt n} }}+\frac 12\sum_{n=p+1}^{\infty}\frac{\sin (n)}{n}$$

You could also compare $S_p$ to
$$T_p=1+\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\,\int_{1}^{p} \frac 1 {\sqrt n} C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2n}{\pi }} \right)\,dn$$
$$T_p= \left(1+\sin
   (1)-\sqrt{2 \pi }\, C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }}\right)\right)+\left(\sqrt{2 p \pi } \, C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2p}{\pi
   }}\right)-\sin (p)\right)$$ which is an excellent approximation of $S_p$ (for example, $S_{1000}=40.1431$ while $T_{1000}=39.6654$).

Asymptotically
$$T_p =\sqrt{\frac{p\,\pi }{2}}$$